# Css: Fixed div blocks scrollbar from scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

In my page i have div element which i use as right menu, and I positioned it 0px from the right so that there is no space between menu and edge of the page, but if there is a scroll bar I can not use it, it seems that div covers it somehow (i can use it however by moving my mouse wheel). If i move my div 10px to the left i can use scroll bar but if there is not need for scroll bar, i have an empty space of 10px between edge of the page and div element. Is there any way to fix this with css or javascript(not jquery), so that my div is positioned in dependency of the scroll bar visibility ?

```
 #rightMenu {
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 150px !important;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    //outline: 1px solid green;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    color: #444;
    position: fixed;
    top: 52px;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: You should add your code to your question

Comment: I added it.....

Comment: Add your HTML too. We need a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I really only need information, how to check is scroll bar visible or not, with javascript(no jquery).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to detect whether or not the scroll bar is currently visible.

From: https://tylercipriani.com/blog/2014/07/12/crossbrowser-javascript-scrollbar-detection/

```
var hasScrollbar

if (typeof window.innerWidth === 'number')
  hasScrollbar = window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth

hasScrollbar = hasScrollbar ||
  document.documentElement.scrollHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight
```